# how to get the product details by rest API in Magento1.9?

Tags: api, product-list, web-services

I am using the magento rest api client(postman & restclient) to get the products details but always returning the 404 error. Please see the attached screen shot.I have set all the values in the header.

**OAuth oauth_version="1.0", 
oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
 oauth_nonce="HqwgoI2wH24FsaU",
 oauth_timestamp="1464929692",
 oauth_consumer_key="35781cd8ea16ab9edc4aeb7c132299bd", 
oauth_token="23b8bfd8c51c4d3efdae6bdf451792b9",
 oauth_signature="2SrYBSzOflXyGYk%2FmYIWy8XtzOM%3D"**

[image]

I have created a rest role named as 'pawan' and assign Role Api Resources of catalog product for create,retrieve and update.

[image]

And I have assign all the resources to the rest attribute 'admin' user.
I have created a rest api cosumer and used the given cosumer key and consumer secret in my controller where I am just doing the authentication for the magento consumer and requestiing for the request token and then callback function is called.

class Custom_Restapi_TestController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

```
public function indexAction()
{
    //Basic parameters that need to be provided for oAuth authentication
    //on Magento
     $params = array(
            'siteUrl' => 'http://172.16.10.16/~pmahajan/magento/index.php/oauth',
            'accessTokenUrl' => 'http://172.16.10.16/~pmahajan/magento/index.php/oauth/token',
            'requestTokenUrl' => 'http://172.16.10.16/~pmahajan/magento/index.php/oauth/initiate',
            'authorizeUrl' => 'http://172.16.10.16/~pmahajan/magento/index.php/admin/oauth_authorize',//This URL is used only if we authenticate as Admin user type
            'consumerKey' => '35781cd8ea16ab9edc4aeb7c132299bd',//Consumer key registered in server administration
            'consumerSecret' => 'df759660479433bb61f60d559b7b2192',//Consumer secret registered in server administration
            'callbackUrl' => 'http://172.16.10.16/~pmahajan/magento/index.php/restapi/test/callback',//Url of callback action below
        );
    // Initiate oAuth consumer with above parameters
    $consumer = new Zend_Oauth_Consumer($params);
    // Get request token
    $requestToken = $consumer->getRequestToken();
    // Get session
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
    // Save serialized request token object in session for later use
    $session->setRequestToken(serialize($requestToken));
    // Redirect to authorize URL
    //Zend_Debug::dump( serialize($requestToken) );
    //Zend_Debug::dump( $requestToken );
    $consumer->redirect();
    return;
}

public function callbackAction()
{
//oAuth parameters
   $params = array(
         'siteUrl' => 'http://172.16.10.16/~pmahajan/magento/index.php/oauth',
            'requestTokenUrl' => 'http://172.16.10.16/~pmahajan/magento/index.php/oauth/initiate',
            'accessTokenUrl' => 'http://172.16.10.16/~pmahajan/magento/index.php/oauth/token',
            'consumerKey' => '35781cd8ea16ab9edc4aeb7c132299bd',
            'consumerSecret' => 'df759660479433bb61f60d559b7b2192'
    );


    // Get session
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
    // Read and unserialize request token from session
    $requestToken = unserialize($session->getRequestToken());
  // echo 'request token';print_r($requestToken);
   //echo '<br/>';
    $consumer = new Zend_Oauth_Consumer($params);
    // Using oAuth parameters and request Token we got, get access token
    Mage::log('Get Array:' . print_r($_GET, true) );
    $acessToken = $consumer->getAccessToken($_GET, $requestToken);

    $restClient = $acessToken->getHttpClient($params);
    // Set REST resource URL
   $restClient->setUri('http://172.16.10.16/~pmahajan/magento/index.php/api/rest/products');
    // In Magento it is neccesary to set json or xml headers in order to work
    $restClient->setHeaders('Accept', 'application/json');
    // Get method
    $restClient->setMethod(Zend_Http_Client::GET);
    //Make REST request
    $response = $restClient->request();
    // Here we can see that response body contains json list of products
    print_r($acessToken);
    //Zend_Debug::dump($response);
    return;
}
```

}

In the callback function I am getting the accessToken and accessSecret and these are used in the postman header.

Now I am hitting the URL in rest client postman :
http://172.16.10.16/~pmahajan/magento/index.php/api/rest/products?limit=2

but it is returning the 404 error. If anyone has any idea please suggest me. Thank You.